# ssl certificate and redirection of traffic from www to nonwww

Tags: redirect, ssl-certificate

I bought an SSL certificate for my domain and when I access the site typing http://example.com the url is being redirected to https://example.com , but the url www.example.com unfortunately is not. So I need to redirect the www traffic to nonwww, so the site is secure in both cases for visitors to read. I need to edit the .htacces file by removing the comment delimiter from the following lines.

```
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I did but it made no difference.
How do I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `#` infront of the rule.
Every rule that has a hash infront doesn't get executed in .htaccess